# What is the best practice for securing MySQL passwords as well as managing multiple accounts?

Tags: php, mysql

My question is two parts. The first is of most importance to me.

I'm developing a website that requires routine inserts and removal of rows, as well as creation and deletion of entire tables. However, if I have only one account to MySQL, I'm essentially giving them a high level access to my database. Because of that, I'd prefer to keep user rights to a minimum depending on the task at hand. For instance, if one action requires only the insertion of a row, then I'll have one account for that. I'm curious as to the management of these multiple accounts - or if it's even practical.

Right now, I'm planning on creating a database connection class in php, and create class extensions to the main that contains the username and password of the specified account.

This begs my second question.

I've read a few of the discussions on this site as well as others that seem to suggest either creating a default account or placing the files outside of document root. Obviously,
I can't create a a default because of the multiple accounts.

Basically, am I going about this correctly?

If anyone has more experience in this area, any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: i have one account for all actions, the mysql account settings is not where you handle this kind of user privileges issue. I don't know of any third party script that uses more than one set of db login credentials

Comment: Really? I've seen several examples of issuing privileges with SQL code to particular accounts.

Comment: neat, name them i want to check em out. no CMS that i have seen does it or e-commerce app, but there's always a first.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html - and I mean in reference to privileges and restrictions on certain accounts. In terms of multiple accounts in php scripts, I haven't seen many that I can pull off the top of my head.

Comment: ? name the applications that use multiple mysql users with different privilege settings. well yes it can be done, but i have never seen a third party application that does it

Comment: @Dagon phpMyAdmin has a separate [control user](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#controluser) that's different from the user logged in to view the database contents.

Comment: @MidnightLightning yes but that's kind of  a specific case being a management tool for a database.

Comment: @Dagon Mediawiki can have a separate [wgDBadminuser](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBadminuser) set for maintenance scripts that need elevated permissions

Comment: Essentially, all this is saying is that it's more practical to create one user account with the minimum privileges based on constraints.

Comment: @MidnightLightning thanks, not convinced by the approach. anyway SO is NOT a chat site. OP should be asking specific questions :-)

Comment: @Dagon You made a specific request for examples, and so I gave them. Whether you're convinced is another matter, but you can't say you've "never seen that" now.

Answer (score 0):

Your database password is going to be in cleartext in a PHP file somewhere on your server in order for your script to connect. No one can see the source of your PHP file through a web request unless there's an error on the page, so ensure that all means of logging in to the server and viewing the source files uses strong passwords. Ensure the file permissions of your PHP files are only readable by the owner and the apache process for stronger security.

Then if you have one user account on your SQL server with all user rights and a password that's 100 characters long of random characters, that password won't be brute-forced in your lifetime, and you'll never need to type it in. It will be in one location in your PHP script, and as long as you secure that source file, you have reasonable security with only one account.

Comment: That's what I was figuring. One reason I ask about security of MySQL passwords is that I recently saw a rather high traffic site dump most of a php file to me with every password I would ever need. Also, I personally don't feel comfortable with having one account that could drop an entire table - for that small possibility of leaving an unsanitized string.

Comment: Use PDO objects to help keep input sanitized, and don't store the database password in a variable; use it directly in the database connector and perpetuate the connection, so there's no random password hanging out in variable memory space.

Comment: I'm using PDO right now, but I hadn't thought of not storing it as a variable - good idea.

Comment: And of course do periodic backups so you can roll back if there's a `DROP TABLE` you didn't expect.